# transform bat command into powershell

Tags: powershell

i have a problem to trasform a bat program on powershel

this is the bat program, I don't know how to set the parameters

```
SET AUTOSPLIT_INPUT_FOLDER=C:\prova\
SET AUTOSPLIT_CONFIG_FILE=C:\prova\pgm\prova.apr
SET AUTOSPLIT_BAT_ENABLE=ON
SET AUTOSPLIT_MODE=Split
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /n /h
```

thanks

I tried launching the program from powershell by simply entering the parameters, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$env is a variable in PowerShell that is used to access operating system environment variables. By using $env, you can access and modify existing environment variables or create new environment variables.

```
$env:AUTOSPLIT_INPUT_FOLDER = "C:\prova\"
$env:AUTOSPLIT_CONFIG_FILE = "C:\prova\pgm\prova.apr"
$env:AUTOSPLIT_BAT_ENABLE = "ON"
$env:AUTOSPLIT_MODE = "Split"
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" -ArgumentList ("/n", "/h")
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks